# Laravel exception if api return json, if website return default page

Tags: laravel

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ( $request->route()->getPrefix() == 'api' ) {
        some code......

        return response()->json($response, $status);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I have a website content site & api both.

I want my exception return json when user request api

If user request is not api, it will return the default page.

But when I put logic into function render, the default one got error.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$request->wantsJson()` and check if the route is prefixed with `api`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ( $request->wantsJson() && $request->is('api/*')) {
        some code......

        return response()->json($response, $status);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

See here for `wantsJson()` method, and other useful `Request` methods: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_wantsJson

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what your question is. But you can detect if you should return a JSON response or not using the `wantsJson()` method. For example the code should instead read to say:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ( $request->wantsJson()) {
        some code......

        return response()->json($response, $status);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Laravel should automatically detect this and return a JSON response for exceptions if you are making a JSON request. The fact it isn't doing this, I would check to make sure you are making a JSON request and not a standard HTTP request.

Comment: the return value for `wantsJson()` is boolean, it doesn't return path, or any part of the path

Comment: Good spot, just noticed I forgot to remove that from the original code.